# python memory-profiler giving no attribute error with pickle load

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I am trying to use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) but it is giving pickling error.
In my code I am loading a object from a pickle file and the code is working fine but when I am running it with memory profiler it gives "'module' object has no attribute" error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the import mechanism rather than invoking `python -m memory_profiler`, ie.

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def func():
    …
    data = pickle.load(open('myfile', 'rb'))
    …
```

I’m not able to give a clear explanation of why that works.